My back is not growing as I want / I want it to grow
In the book, Grammar in use 5th ed. 
As = in the same way as, in the same condition as.
We use 'as' with subject (S) + verb (V):- 
I didn’t move anything. I left everything as it was.
You should have done it as I showed you.
can we only use subject + verb after 'as'? or we can use longer phrases, like 

My back is not growing as I want it to grow.
My back is not growing as I want.

I mean if I want to say something more specific, would the first sentence be correct?

"My back is not growing" is nonsensical. My garden is not growing as I want it to.

The first version "as I want it to grow" is not more specific; it is more explicit. The bracketed phrase is implicit in "I want [it to grow]".  The word as establishes a comparison and the comparands are understood to be the actual growth vs the desired growth.

@Lambie If you have a spinal issue that becomes apparent as a teenager, your back could very well not grow as you want it to.

@Kaia No. It's the spine that doesn't grow straight, not the "back".

I think "as I want[ed] it to grow" is correct. But I think "My garden isn't growing how I wanted it to grow" slightly more common.

@Lambie I should have taken some other example instead of using 'my back'.But people use this in the gym and to talk about in terms of muscles.

@Kaia in normal conversation, the point is to not have to repeat the verb: how I wanted it to. As I wanted it to. same thing. Action verbs do not require repetition.

@Lambie you mean ellipsis?
